# Change UITableView Cell Selection Style to Red

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to change the UITableView cell selection style from default blue to red. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting the cells' `selectedBackgroundView.image`, per this [tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html). That would give you the option of creating a nice gradient-based selection image, too.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need an image or to subclass the cell. Simply do something like the following when creating the cell in your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
            cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
            cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you sub-class UITableViewCell, you can modify its highlighted and selected UI behavior by overriding following methods.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

For example:

```
- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];
    if (highlighted) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *selectedBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        selectedBackground.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackground];
```

you can try something like this